# How to solve the latex error in TexStudio 4.2.2?

Tags: latex, texstudio

I am using simple template on texstudio 4.2.2
The template is simple and no errors in syntax and everything. But I receive following error message while I try to debug & run.

```
Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "thesis".tex
```

What is wrong here? Do i need to install any library then which?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a tex distribution like texlive or miktex installed?

Comment: Yes I have Miktex 2.9, Do I have to reinstall it as well or just update will be  okay?

Comment: That's good. TexStudio probably just needs a bit of help to find it. Can you open the texstudio settings and go to the `Build` tab. Then at the very bottom should be a field `Commands ($PATH)`. Try to add the path to `pdflatex.exe` there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I solved the problem with the upgrade version of TexStudio by reinstalling it.